# Real numbers in interval notation

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

If I want to denote the set $\mathbb{R}$ in $[a,b]$ interval notation, is it correct to say:
$
(-\infty, \infty)?
$

Comment: That is the usual way of writing $\mathbb R$, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$